# ActionScript: Automated Test Frameworks

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've just been tasked with finding automated actionscript frameworks. Can anyone offer the best out there? I'm just beginning to write the code for my project. Is it better for me to keep my MXML and AS in separate files so I can more easily integrate with any frameworks....or does it even matter?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FlexUnit](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexunit/FlexUnit) is a good unit testing framework.

For continuous integration, I've used [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [flex-mojos](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/). That will require a bit more work to setup, but it is well worth the effort.

If you need functional testing, I haven't used it myself, but I have heard that [Flex Monkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/flexmonkey) is pretty good.

Comment: +1 for all of the above. Also, check out mockolate for mocking - mock4as works, but requires a lot of code writing. http://mockolate.org/

Comment: Aside from Flex Monkey, I'd also make a mention of RIATest and QTP for UI testing.

Comment: For continuous integration we're going with Cruise Control but I'll check out FlexUnit; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [AsUnit](http://asunit.org/) I've used it in combination with both [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) build manager and TeamCity with great results

Comment: btw. jenkins is the new hudson. hudson still exists, but support for it has disappeared.

Comment: Right, forgot about that. It's been a while!

Comment: That shouldn't matter. ASUnit is the framework to execute all of your tests. The unit tests you write will be the ones that leverage the specific API of Flex 4